# Hibernate Table per Hierarchy How to

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

I would like to use hibernate to contain a hierarchy of objects, however the discriminator column is a foreign key to another table that contains the CODE defining the subclass type.

Is it possible to specify the code from the joined table as the discriminator, or do I have to use the key values and hope the keys stay consistent?

e.g. discriminator="square|circle" v.s. discriminator="0|1"

**table: shape**

```
area=25   shape_type_fk=0
area=10   shape_type_fk=1
```

**table: shape_types**

```
ID CODE
0  square
1  circle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test shows that you could do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">

  <class name="Shape" abstract="true">
    <id name="id"/>
    <discriminator formula="select CODE from SHAPE_TYPES st where st.ID=SHAPE_TYPE"/>
    <version name="version"/>

    <subclass name="Square" discriminator-value="square"/>
    <subclass name="Circle" discriminator-value="circle"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now this mapping will not create the `SHARE_TYPE` table that is referenced in the formula Nor does it add the `SHAPE_TYPE` column to the `SHAPE` table. This you could do in the `import.sql` file that Hibernate reads automatically from the classpath or by mapping another class to this table.

Comment: Maarten's examples works, but needs parens around the discriminator formula, and columns in the subselect must reference the aliased table. Also, using criteria for a subclass results in a correlated subquery, which is very inefficient. I guess I'll have to live without the polymorphic (table per) hierachy.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to use joined-subclass instead of subclass. Details are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html).